# How can I can delete a project in Aperture, but not in Flickr?

Tags: storage, aperture, flickr

I have a Macbook Air as my only computer ; I store my shots on Flickr.

The size of the SSD doesn't allow me to keep all my RAW files on my laptop. So I publish the photographs I like in their final state on Flickr with the built-in feature of Aperture.

When I hit **delete** on a project (in Aperture) the message clearly indicates that all photos synched to any service like Facebook, Flickr or any other **will be deleted**.

How can I can around this without the hacky way of unlinking Aperture from Flickr before deleting the project?

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say that the best solution to this is probably to get an external hard drive, or ten. Having an off-site storage of your files is a very good idea, but relying on it as the sole storage is a notion that fills me with dread.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but for different reasons this is not my current setup. My question remains :-)